# I have installed ubuntu alongside windows vista but Ubuntu won't run

Tags: boot, windows, windows-vista

I installed ubuntu on my pc alongside windows Vista

When I choose to boot ubuntu the PC doesn't run. Can anyone help?

Comment: "It doesn't run" does not give us enough information to help you. In any case, **do not use Wubi**, because it **always** causes trouble.

Answer (score 3):

You can try Boot-repair. Boot-Repair, simple tool to recover access to your Operating Systems. To get Boot-repair you can download it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/)

Once you download the ISO file, go ahead and burn it to a CD, then make sure that your system is set to boot from CD. Boot from the newly created Boot-repair CD, and follow the on-screen instructions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), click the "Create a BootInfo summary" button, then indicate the URL that will appear. Remark: the "Recommended repair" button will repair/reinstall GRUB, which I think is not necessary in your case because you can see the GRUB menu.
2. From the GRUB menu, select the "Previous Linux versions" entry (if it exists), and check if you have the same error with the old kernels.